# Совместное использование Laravel && Git

Tags: git, laravel, github, laravel5

Возник вопрос "**Как правильно клонировать Laravel-проект?**".

Дело в том, что с Laravel, равно как и с Git, пока только разбираюсь. Нашел в интернете материалы как залить проект на гитхаб, сделал для себя [шпаргалку](http://majestio.info/viewtopic.php?id=79) по установке и инициализации. Но, когда выгрузил на гитхаб, заметил, что некоторые каталоги типа "test", "vendor", и другие на гитхаб не выгружаются. Посмотрел файл ".gitignore" - там их много.

Таким образом, если я выполню "git clone" в пустом каталоге - я получу проект неполный. Как правильно клонировать Laravel-проект в пустой каталог? Единственное, что приходит на ум - очистить .gitignore при создании и заливке проекта на гитхаб. Но правильно ли так? А если "нет", то как правильно?

Comment: vendor, test и подобные каталоги/файлы нет необходимости заливать на гитхаб, потому что они создаются при инициализации проекта. Именно поэтому такие каталоги и файлы вносят в .gitignore

Comment: Я понимаю. Но какова тогда последовательность клонирования проекта? Допустим, я создал пустой проект, в него добавил `lavary/laravel-menu`(или добавил потом, в процессе разработки). Это попадает в vendor. Как об этом узнает тот, кто будет клонировать?

Comment: [Из `composer.json`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-json-project-setup).

Comment: @D-side , да, спасибо, я уже разобрался. Есть еще мелочи - опишу в ответе самому себе :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечаю сам себе, может кому-нибудь еще пригодится ...

Клонирование проекта нужно выполнить в несколько этапов:

1. `git clone <проект>`
2. `composer install`
3. Создание под свое окружение файла `.env`

<strike>Остается "повисшим" вопрос, если что-то правилось в пропускаемых каталогах/файлах, например в:</strike>

`vendor\mcamara\laravel-localization\src\config\config.php`

Это нужно править дополнительно как-то. Возможно этот конфиг можно как-то вынести из пропускаемого. Если найду способ, ответ обновлю.

Нельзя править в каталоге `vendor` и подобных. В описании, например `laravel-localization`, есть раздел, как настраивать локальную конфигурацию.

Вопрос решен.